# C++ Operator overloaded using friend function. Attempt to add multiple objects failed

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Why compiler shows 'error' in 2nd case? (I have given link to full program)
Why do I have to use const keyword?

1st case:

```
friend Complex operator + (const Complex &,const Complex &);

Complex c5 = c1+c2+c3+c4;
```

2nd case:

```
friend Complex operator + ( Complex &, Complex &); 

Complex c5 = c1+c2+c3+c4;
```

[1st case Full Program](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/QRmOp1QhjV)  - I get proper Output

[2nd case Full Program](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/xnwY68Q6Dp)  - error: no match for 'operator+'

Answer (score 2):

`Complex&` will not bind to a temporary, `Complex const&` will.

Each `+` returns a temporary.

As a general rule, you want:

```
friend Complex operator + (Complex,const Complex &);
```

but here two `const&` will do.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `c1+c2+c3+c4` is parsed and evaluated as if

```
Complex c5 = operator+(c1, operator+(c2, operator+(c3, c4)));
```

`operator+(c3, c4)` builds and returns a temporary `Complex` object: an rvalue.

**C++ forbids an rvalue to be bound to a non-const lvalue-reference**.

But `operator+(Complex&, Complex&)` takes a non-const lvalue-reference. Hence the error message.

On the other hand, `operator+(Complex const&, Complex const&)` takes references to const lvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Temporaries dont bind to non-const references. When you write this

```
auto c3 = c2 + c1 + c0;
```

then first `c1+c0` will be computed, and the result passed to `c2.operator+()`. When the operator is declared to take a `Complex&` then you cannot pass a temporary, when it takes `const Complex&` then you can. Passing a temporary when a non-const reference is expected is a logic error in 90% of the cases, hence it is forbidden.